# Using a DLL that has data access capabilities causes an error

Tags: c#

I'm at the stage of linking my logic (a DLL) to my UI (winform). My DLL uses EF 4.1.

Here's the line in the myEFContext.Designer.cs that throws the exception:

```
public DispatchContext() : base("name=DispatchContext", "DispatchContext") //<--- This line
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

The exception thrown is (free translation)

```
ArgumentException
The specified connexion name is not found in the configuration [...]
```

If I do the exact same thing from a winform project inside the same solution as my DLL, all works fine.

1. How is it that the UI has to have knowledge of the data source?
2. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's working in the winforms project because there is a connection string in the `app.config`. The library doesn't use a config and/or the connection string is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the source and see what connection string name it is looking for you can do this by decompiling the dll with [Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)

Note: I do not have any financial relationship  with any of these products